# XSLT Grouping for HTML

Tags: xslt

I have data for images like this:

```
<data>
    <image>
        <type>preview</type>
        <pageNr>1</pageNr>
        <url>5981-211.png</url>
    </image>
    <image>
        <type>thumbnail</type>
        <pageNr>1</pageNr>
        <url>5549a_aldj_thumb.png</url>
    </image>
    <image>
        <type>big thumb</type>
        <url>47697-4921.png</url>
    </image>
    <image>
        <type>preview</type>
        <pageNr>2</pageNr>
        <url>491-d91.png</url>
    </image>
    <image>
    <type>thumbnail</type>
        <pageNr>2</pageNr>
        <url>491-d91_thumb.png</url>
    </image>
</data>
```

And I want to create the following HTML output:

```
<a href="5981-211.png" title="1">
    <img src="5549a_aldj_thumb.png" />
</a>
<a href="491-d91.png" title="2">
    <img src="491-d91_thumb.png" />
</a>
```

For every `preview` there is a `thumbnail` with the same `pageNr`.

How can I group the data and nest the `<img>` into the `<a>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with the use of a key to lookup the "thumbnail" images

```
<xsl:key name="thumb" match="image[type='thumbnail']" use="pageNr" />
```

You would start off by selecting the "preview" elements

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="image[type='preview']"/>
```

And in the template that matches this, you would create the `a` tag, and then select the child "thumbnail" elements using the key

```
<a href="{url}" title="{pageNr}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('thumb', pageNr)" />
</a>
```

And in the template that matches the thumbnails, you would create the `img` tag like so:

```
 <img src="{url}" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="thumb" match="image[type='thumbnail']" use="pageNr" />

    <xsl:template match="/data">
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="image[type='preview']"/>
      </body>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="image[type='preview']">
        <a href="{url}" title="{pageNr}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('thumb', pageNr)" />
        </a>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="image[type='thumbnail']">
        <img src="{url}" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```